# Calendar loading or javascript error

Tags: php, jquery

I got a calendar that load fine here : http://studioteknik.info/testinfo/salle-1/ and I got the real site (a copy) where the calendar dont work (or dont load) : http://stada.ca/salle-1/

The problem is firebug, google webdev tool, html validator, removing all plugin, installing removing, changind theme.. i have DONE all that many times...

now i dont have any more tools/idea how to find the bug and what is the problem...

can anyone have and idea whay the calendar is loading fine on first (test) site and NOT loading on the REAL wordking site ....

if it's a jquery error... i have remove all jquery and add only one... it does not help !..

i am LOST !

Comment: Just as told by kaesve, i reinstall wp Super cache and delete all the cache, and delete the plugin properly.. and BAM... everything went OK !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I look in the chrome devtools console I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

If I then check where that error is coming from, it seems a json.Parse is failing. Why? I pasted the data the page recieves down below

```
"{"2013-11-26":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"100","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-11-27":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"100","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-11-28":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"100","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-11-29":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"100","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-11-30":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"100","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-11":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-12":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-13":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-14":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-15":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-16":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-17":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-18":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-19":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-20":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-21":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-22":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-23":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-24":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"},"2013-12-25":{"available":"1","bind":"0","hours":{"00:00":{"available":"","bind":"0","info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"none"}},"hours_definitions":[{"value":"00:00"}],"info":"","notes":"","price":"50","promo":"","status":"available"}}<!-- WP Super Cache is installed but broken. The constant WPCACHEHOME must be set in the file wp-config.php and point at the WP Super Cache plugin directory. -->"
```

If you scroll to the end you'll see:

```
<!-- WP Super Cache is installed but broken. The constant WPCACHEHOME must be set in the file wp-config.php and point at the WP Super Cache plugin directory. -->
```

So, there's something wrong with your wordpress installation and not the webpage.

Comment: i use only the right click inspect element... and i dont have that infos.... will install devtool asap

Comment: Men, you rock... you fix my 2 week old problem in 1 hours ! a MILLION THANKS ! xx

Comment: MEN, i love stackoverflow <3